# patching boto3.resource and resource.Table method for unit testing

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

Here is my class:

```
# Production.py
import boto3


class Production(object):
    resource = boto3.resource('dynamodb', 'us-west-2')

    def __init__(self):
        self.table = Production.resource.Table('employee')
```

I am trying to test that resource.Table is called with arg 'employee'. I wrote a unit test for it

```
def test_init():
   with patch('Production.boto3.resource') as resource:
       mock_resource = MagicMock()
       resource.return_value = mock_resource
       pd = Production()
       resource.assert_called_with('dynamodb', 'us-west-2')
       table = resource.return_value.Table.return_value

       table.assert_called_with('employee')


test_init()
```

But it doesn't seem to work... Can some one help me how to test this?

Answer (score 4):

When you patch an object it mocks all of its methods for you. So (I didn't test the code but) I think just:

```
def test_resource_is_called_with_correct_params():
    with patch('Production.boto3') as mock_boto:
        Production()
        mock_boto.resource.assert_called_once_with('dynamodb', 'us-west-2')
```

will do the first part of your test. I would then test the init function separately in another test, which is clearer easier and more simple (generally aim to test one thing per test):

```
def test_table_is_called_with_correct_params():
    with patch('Production.boto3') as mock_boto:
        Production()
        mock_resource = mock_boto.resource.return_value
        mock_resource.Table.assert_called_once_with('employee')
```

I would say a couple of things about this though:

1. It's nice to group your tests into a class which organises your tests. Also when you get subclass TestsCase you get a bunch of methods that come with it such as self.assertDictEqual that will provide good meaningful output and work well will test runners like nose2. So do something like:

   ```
   class TestProduction(unittest.TestCase):
       def test1():
           pass

       def test2():
           pass
   ```
2. The stuff you are testing there is basically hard coded so these tests are not really meaningful. You are just testing that the language works. I would learn to test behaviour rather than implementation ... So what do you want you class to do? Sit down and think about it first before you write the class. Then you can write the specs out and use those specs to design your tests before you even start coding.